# need to change width and height of slider, but images getting overlapped

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am thinking of changing the width and height of homepage slider for this site: `http://www.1000meninchrist.com/`

I tried to change width and height using the following code:

```
<div class="iosSlider" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; overflow: hidden; z-index: 1; width: 720px; height: 490px;"><!-- slider -->
```

My problem is that images are getting overlapped when I'm trying to change width and height of slider. Please suggest me what changes I still need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please apply max-width to the img element:

```
.iosSlider img {
   max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with the code a little bit, I believe you need to change the width of both the iosSlider class as well as the slide class for it to display correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In the CSS
http://www.1000meninchrist.com/skin/frontend/default/beautyshop/css/slider.css

change

```
.iosSlider {    
overflow: hidden;
width: 690px;
height: 490px;
margin:auto 0 0px;
float:left;
}
```

to

```
.iosSlider {
overflow: hidden;
width: 720px;
height: 490px;
margin:auto 0 0px;
float:left;
}
```

Comment: you just changed width size, if you do just change width size, images gets oevrlapped, thats why my problem..